# Testing symfony commands not working

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I'd like to test a symfony command using `CommandTester` as explained here http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/console/introduction.html#testing-commands.

The command I want to test removes records having the column `decision` set to true. (More detail in the code below)

```php
public function testMyCommand()
{
    // .....
    // Updating the database
    $res = $this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->createQueryBuilder()
        ->update('MyBundle:MyEntity', 'me')
        ->set('me.decision', true)
        ->where('me.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', 4);

    // The command is meant to seek for all entities having *decision* set to true and delete them
    $application = new Application($this->client->getKernel());
    $application->add(new CronQuotidienCommand());

    $command = $application->find('myproject:mycmd');
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
    $commandTester->execute(array('command' => $command->getName()));

    $this->assertEmpty($this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->findBy(array('decision' => true));
}
```

Although the test fails, there is one `MyEntity`, whose id equals to 4, with the column `decision` set to `true`, which means that `$commandTester->execute(array('command' => $command->getName()));` didn't find any `MyEntity` with `decision` set to `true` (referesh matter?).

The surprise is when I replace

```
    $application = new Application($this->client->getKernel());
    $application->add(new CronQuotidienCommand());

    $command = $application->find('myproject:mycmd');
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
    $commandTester->execute(array('command' => $command->getName()));
```

with

```php
    shell_exec('php ' . $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/console myproject:mycmd');
```

it does work.

Any ideas? thx

Comment: 1) `$res = ....->setParameter('id', 4);`, but where is thats query execution? 2) are you sure $em->flush called when changes made in ur command? 3) such functional tests are waste of time, prefer unit ones 4) shell_exec is almost always bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

$arguments = array(
    // ...
);
$input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
$output = new ConsoleOutput();
$returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
```

instead of:

```
$commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
$commandTester->execute(array('command' => $command->getName()));
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo only in my post

Comment: So my answer is still valid.

Comment: No need to specify id => 4 because it's the only element in my database of test

Comment: I updated my answer, if this is not ok you should certainly give a part of the code of your command and the way you create the test database.

Comment: Gonna try it and let you know